# .net - Problems with Array.Sort and Array.BinarySearch - culture and globalization

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to sort an array containing a list of words and search the same using binarysearch. For certain reasons, the word-list must always be sorted using the sorting-rules of "en-US" i.e. American Regional Settings. The code will run under various international Operating Systems and of course, this will mean that the word-list will be sorted differently according to the local Regional Settings in use. One problem could arise on a computer/device running with Lithuanian Regional Settings. Why? Because the letter "**Y**" in most languages is sorted like X-**Y**-Z while in Lithuanian, the sort order is I-**Y**-J. This behavior would create havoc to my program.

On a desktop-PC, I could change momentarily the Regional Settings into American English by using:

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")

However, since I am developing for Windows Mobile (CF.NET), this piece of code is not possible to implement.

I found some hacks which could let me change the Regional Settings on the device programmatically but they are not "official" and considered risky so I prefer avoiding these.

So my question is: how can I force Array.Sort and Array.BinarySearch to use CultureInfo = "en-US" while sorting and searching regardless of the Regional Settings set on the device?

I believe I could use:

```
Public Shared Function BinarySearch(Of T) ( _
    array As T(), _
    value As T, _
    comparer As IComparer(Of T) _
) As Integer
```

and implement Comparer to take into consideration CultureInfo (and set it to "en-US") but I don't know how to do that despite trying hard. If anyone could post some sample-code in VB.Net or C# or an explanation of how to do it, I would be very grateful.

If you are aware of any alternative solution which works in CF.Net, then, of course, I am all ears.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I will consider Twanfosson's answer as the accepted solution since my question clearly stated that I wanted to maintain an association with the English language.

However, in means of flexibility, I believe Guffa's answer is the best one. Why? Let's use another example: In German, the letter **Ö** is sorted **Ö**-X-Z while in Swedish and Finnish, the order is X-Z-**Ö**. In Estonian the sort order is Z-**Ö**-X. Complicated, isn't it? Guffa's solution will let me force Swedish sorting-order (changing CultureInfo) on a device running under German Regional settings. Using **Comparer.DefaultInvariant** with its association to English wouldn't help in this case, probably the letter **Ö** would end up with O. Therefore my vote will go to Guffa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it not possible to use the [Invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) culture?

> InvariantCulture retrieves an instance
>   of the invariant culture. It is
>   associated with the English language
>   but not with any country/region.

Using the invariant culture would make this trivial.

```
Array.Sort( myArray, Comparer.DefaultInvariant );

Array.BinarySearch( myArray, myString, Comparer.DefaultInvariant );
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the answer to both is to implement a comparer. Create a class that implements the `IComparer(Of String)` interface and has it's own `CultureInfo` object that it uses to compare the strings:

```
Public Class StringComparerEnUs
   Implements IComparer(Of String)

   Private _culture As CultureInfo

   Public Sub New()
      _culture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
   End Sub

   Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String)
      Return String.Compate(x, y, false, _culture)
   End Function

End Class
```

Now you can use it to sort the strings:

```
Array.Sort(theArray, New StringComparerEnUs())
```

and to find them:

```
pos = BinarySearch(theArray, "Dent, Arthur", new StringComparerEnUs())
```

(The class can, of course, be made a bit more general by accepting a culture string in the constructor, and you can also add a variable to make use of the `ignoreCase` parameter in the `String.Compare` call.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class EnglishComparer : IComparer<string>
{
  static CultureInfo __english = new CultureInfo("en-US");

  public int Compare(string x, string y)
  {
    return string.Compare(x, y, __english, CompareOptions.None);
  }
}
```